# fixed point subtraction for two's complement data

Tags: twos-complement, fixed-point

I have some real data. For example `+2` and `-3`. These data are represented in two's complement fixed point with 4 bit binary value where MSB represents the sign bit and number of fractional bit is zero.

So +2 = **0**010

```
-3 = 1101
```

addition of this two numbers is `(+2) + (-3)=-1`

```
(0010)+(1101)=(1111)
```

But in case of subtraction `(+2)-(-3)` what should i do?

Is it needed to take the two's complement of `1101 (-3)` again and add with `0010`?

Comment: What is tows? And these are pure integers, not fixed-point values

Comment: sorry for the error. It should be two's complement. I know these are pure integers but above example can be extended for fractional value also.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate `-(-3)` in binary and than simply sums it with the other values.

With two's complement, evaluate the opposite of a number is pretty simple: just apply the NOT binary operation to every digits except for the less significant bit. The equation below uses the *tilde* to rapresent the NOT operation of a single bit and assumed to deal with integer rapresented by n bits (`n = 4` in your example):

[image]

In your example (with an informal notation): `-(-3) = -(1101) = 0011`